# Adding an XML Documentation Comment file for a school project in Visual Code (C#)

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, visual-studio-code

I have made a school project that my teacher will check later on.

I am trying to add some Documentation Comments in Visual Studio Code with the help of a [plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=k--kato.docomment) that allows me to write `///` which makes the xml code automatically.

I have read from the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/include) about XML Documentation that you can make a seperate XML file rather than clutter the code with comments but i have been having a hard time getting it to work.

Here is an example:

```
 ///<include file='docs.xml' path='docs/members[@name="program"]/Select/*'/>
        public static bool Select (ConsoleKey input) {
            ConsoleKeyInfo key = Console.ReadKey (true);
            if (key.Key == input) {
                return true;

            }
            return false;
        }
```

This is what the doc.xml file has about this method:

```
 <doc>
  <members name="program">
    <Select>
        <summary>
        Summarizes a way to detect <paramref name ="input"/>.
        </summary>
        <returns>
        true when <paramref name = "input"/> is detected. 
        </returns>
        <param name="input"> Checks what key it should detect.</param>
        <example>
        <code>

            string outputToConsole = "Hello World!";
            void Main () {
                if (Selecting.Select (ConsoleKey.Spacebar)) {
                   Console.WriteLine (outputToConsole);
          //Prints "Hello World" when key "Spacebar" is pressed!
                }
            }

        </code>
      </example>
    </Select>
```

It currently does not work (It does not show a description on the method at all) and i have been racking my head over this.

Comment: usually VS wuild create an xml-file with the exact same name as your assembly that holds all the documentation from your code. This file includes every comment with `///` in front. So I don´t understand what your actual problem with that file is? Doesn´t it get generated? What does it contain?

Comment: My problem is that despite adding in the `<include>` tag next to the method, there is no documentation on the method. Also, im working on Visual Studio Code! NOT Visual Studio.

Comment: From the site I can't tell if this is supported in Code. But the basics should be done by the compiler and should work.

Comment: "does not work (It does not show a description on the method ..." - first thing to check is if it generates that other xml file. To see if you got `compile with: -doc:DocFileName.xml` right.

Comment: But reconsider: the reason for this feature is separate maintenance ('check out'), is that really an issue? I would go for the clutter. Ctrl+O+M neatly folds it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The  documentation says (emphasis mine):

> This is an alternative to placing documentation comments directly in your source code file. **By putting the documentation in a separate file, you can apply source control to the documentation separately from the source code**. One person can have the source code file checked out and someone else can have the documentation file checked out.

I do understand the motivation behind this, but **if you decide to use a separate file you can no longer use Visual Studio autocomplete/intellisense to generate the XML elements for you, and you'll need to learn the schema/syntax of the XML documentation file**.

Also, as the assembly gets bigger, so will the XML file. In the real world this file could have 1000s of lines of code. From a maintenance and source control perspective, I'd rather have the documentation in the c# source files. I honestly think it's not worth the trouble.

Anyway, if you still want to use the external files there are a few tricks you can use.

Consider a class library named `FileDemo`. Righ-click the project > `Properties` > `Build` and then tick the checkbox `XML Documentation File`:

[image: Project properties]

This will generate the XML documentation file on build:

[image: Solution Explorer]

And now the funny part. As I mentioned before, the XML documentation file has a particular syntax you'll need to learn. The best way to do it is to add some XML documentation to existing classes, methods etc and check the generated XML. For example, considering the following namespaces and classes:

**namespace FileDemo**

```
namespace FileDemo
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This is a class
    /// </summary>
    public class Class1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Does nothing
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="text">Just some text</param>
        public void DoNothing(string text)
        {

        }
    }

        /// <summary>
    /// This is another class
    /// </summary>
    public class Class2
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Bla bla
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="text">Just some text</param>
        public void DoSomething(string text)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

**namespace FileDemo.AnotherNamespace**

```
namespace FileDemo.AnotherNamespace
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Yet another class
    /// </summary>
    public class Class3
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets something
        /// </summary>
        public string Foo { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a new instance of <see cref="Class3"/>
        /// </summary>
        public Class3()
        {

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This method is supposed to calculate something
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="firstValue">First value</param>
        /// <param name="secondValue">Second value</param>
        /// <returns>The result of the calculation</returns>
        public int Calculate(int firstValue, int secondValue)
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

After building the project, the generated documentation file is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<doc>
    <assembly>
        <name>FileDemo</name>
    </assembly>
    <members>
        <member name="T:FileDemo.AnotherNamespace.Class3">
            <summary>
            Yet another class
            </summary>
        </member>
        <member name="P:FileDemo.AnotherNamespace.Class3.Foo">
            <summary>
            Gets or sets something
            </summary>
        </member>
        <member name="M:FileDemo.AnotherNamespace.Class3.#ctor">
            <summary>
            Creates a new instance of <see cref="T:FileDemo.AnotherNamespace.Class3"/>
            </summary>
        </member>
        <member name="M:FileDemo.AnotherNamespace.Class3.Calculate(System.Int32,System.Int32)">
            <summary>
            This method is supposed to calculate something
            </summary>
            <param name="firstValue">First value</param>
            <param name="secondValue">Second value</param>
            <returns>The result of the calculation</returns>
        </member>
        <member name="T:FileDemo.Class1">
            <summary>
            This is a class
            </summary>
        </member>
        <member name="M:FileDemo.Class1.DoNothing(System.String)">
            <summary>
            Does nothing
            </summary>
            <param name="text">Just some text</param>
        </member>
        <member name="T:FileDemo.Class2">
            <summary>
            This is another class
            </summary>
        </member>
        <member name="M:FileDemo.Class2.DoSomething(System.String)">
            <summary>
            Bla bla
            </summary>
            <param name="text">Just some text</param>
        </member>
    </members>
</doc>
```

As you can see, there is a particular schema/syntax that you need to learn for each element you're trying to document (classes, methods, properties, constructors, parameters, return types, etc).

Comment: Well poop. Thank you for the info, it has shed a bit of light into what im dealing with. This did give me an idea. Since i have Visual Studio and Visual Code, if i ever make a project in Visual Code, couldnt i just open the project in Visual Studio and then build it with that same XML file?

Comment: @SpyrotheA.L.D not sure, TBH I never used Visual Code. My advice is: save yourself some pain and add the XML documentation in the code, not in external files - unless your teacher asked you to use an external file!

Comment: My teacher doesnt mind me having a documentation in code. I explained the reason why i wanted a seperate file for my documentation and he understands my motivations. He said that he was going to look at it. For now, ill make most of my documentations dead last in my code so that it atleast is understandable to read. :)

Comment: Yes the intention of having a separate file for maintenance is good, but 'the road to hell is paved with good intentions' :-) Honestly, documentation becomes outdated very easily, and it's easier to ask a developer that adds or changes the code to add/update the documentation immediately in the same source code he's working on, rather than having to edit a big XML file containing the full documentation of the assembly.

Comment: I just remembered another good reason for NOT using a separate XML file - as the assembly gets bigger, so will the XML file. My example file has 53 lines only, but in the real world this file would have 1000s of lines of code. From a maintenance and source control perspective, I'd rather change the documentation in the c# source file(s)

Comment: Im getting too spooked now. :S